# "just married" or "just wed"?

Tags: phrases, differences

I saw this for the first time in something recent: ["just wed"](http://www.google.fr/imgres?imgurl=http://photo.parismatch.com/media/photos2/2.-photos-people/tetes-couronnees/les-plus-belles-photos-du-mariage/just-wed/2923401-1-fre-FR/just-wed_galleryphoto_paysage_std.jpg&imgrefurl=http://www.parismatch.com/People-Match/Le-Mariage-de-William-et-Kate/Le-mariage/Photos/William-et-Kate-Les-plus-belles-photos-du-mariage-du-siecle/Just-Wed-278355/&usg=__vpvNx0a0rVsQ_VrEyA50uK5XxQA=&h=537&w=924&sz=68&hl=fr&start=0&sig2=Ev3HGs7F15nXAePEHsd_eQ&zoom=1&tbnid=SO4Z8t54OmS0AM%3a&tbnh=98&tbnw=168&ei=gc2-TceaFIOW8QPP2tC4Bg&prev=/search?q=just%2bwed&um=1&hl=fr&safe=off&client=ubuntu&sa=N&channel=cs&biw=1066&bih=552&tbm=isch&um=1&itbs=1&iact=hc&vpx=104&vpy=96&dur=1119&hovh=171&hovw=295&tx=187&ty=79&page=1&ndsp=16&ved=1t:429,r:0,s:0).

I wonder how and when it is used (BrE only, under certain conditions). Does it mean exactly the same as "married"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just one of those English things where there's a choice between Saxon-German or Norman-Latin words.

*Wed* is Germanic, meaning to wager/bet/promise; *to marry* comes from the Latin.

Comment: @Matthew, "accepted your answer" would mean he agrees with me, while "accepted answer"-ed means he clicked the button. I suppose it's the difference between voting for a candidate and actually believing in them ;-)

Comment: @matthew, if you look at the caption of the button, it says "Click to set this answer as your accepted answer", and not "click to accept this answer" :p. @Martin Becket I actually agree with you. But "I accept your answer" have a tone I don't like, plus it could mean that I didn't find other answer acceptable, which is not the case.

Answer (score 7):

Both "just married" and "just wed" mean the same thing.

In my experience, I have seen "just married" more than "just wed." A Google Ngram confirms the usage of just married as more frequent:

[image: just married vs. just wed]

Perhaps the shorter phrase was used to fit on the license plate.

You will also see "newlyweds" to refer to people who have just been married.

Answer (score 0):

They mean the same thing.

> Just wed

Sounds better, in my opinion.

Comment: Now to me, "Just married" sounds better. I suspect "Wed" with its OE origins seems more informal and even dialect.